# Why $S^{2} - C$ is locally connected

Tags: general-topology

I read book of Munkres in Separation theorem in Plane , he said : " Let $C$ be a compact subspace of $S^{2}$ ". Then  why $S^{2}-C$ is locally connected ?  It's $61.1$ theorem .
Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 4):

Because $S^2$ is locally connected, and an open subspace of a locally connected space is locally connected. $C$ is compact, so closed, and so $S^2 - C$ is an open subspace of $S^2$. Hence the claim.

Comment: So why $U$ is a  component of $S^{2} - C$ then $U - b$ is connected with $b$ is a point in $S^{2} - C$ . I can't understand soluntion in Munkres's book . Can you explain it for me ?